# How to create many div's with 100% height?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

**I need a html document, that contains multiple div's with 100% height (screen filling) one below the other.**

I have tried to apply every element a height of 100%, but that won't work seamless nor clean.

Maybe there is a option with JavaScript? I don't have an idea.

Please suggest me your solutions.

chris

Comment: Why would one need something like that? Try positiong absolute and supply explicit height (in pixels) using innerWidth.

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Comment: If one is bellow the first one, then the first one is not 100%. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @Kooilnc: I think it's not your business to know why I need that :)

@Anton: You have several div's one below the other. And now imagine you are clicking an link (anchor) to go to the next div - and that has to fill the screen/browser-window too.

I hope that helps you :)

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: maybe it's not, but it's usefull information if you want answers. You revealed your intentions anyway to Anton, so i'll try an answer then.

Comment: @Kooilnc: Yea, but your question wasn't very objective. "Why would one need something like that?" sounds very offensive buddy. - Back to Topic.

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: ehr, maybe my english isn't very sensitive to subleties like that, being dutch and all. It wasn't my intention to be offensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this link](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144) that shows assigning a 100% height via css. I tried it in FF3.6 and IE6, and it seems to work, though as with all things IE, it kind of goes a little long.
hth